# Warning from CompiledFunction is permanently off silently after generating for 3 times, bug or feature?

Tags: warning-messages, compile

I've been vaguely aware of this behavior for a long time but never looked into it. Consider this sample:

```
(* I know the proper definition is: *) 
(* test = Compile[{{a, _Complex}}, Sqrt@a]; *)
test = Compile[a, Sqrt@a];

test[-1]
test[-1]
test[-1]
(* You can split the cell here *)
test[-1]
```

Version 7 behavior:

[image]

Version 8 (and later) behavior:

[image]

As shown above, since version 8, after the `CompiledFunction::cfn` is generated for 3 times, it silently disappears (nothing like `General::stop` comes out) and no longer shows up.

So far, the only way I find that can make the warning appear again is to re-evaluate the definition of `test`.

Is this a bug or new-added feature? If the latter, is it possible to turn on the warning `CompiledFunction::cfn` without re-evaluating definition of `test` in and after version 8?

Comment: The same happens in versions 11.3 and 12.3

Comment: @mattiav27 Just tested in older version. This behavior is introduced in version 8. See the new-added screenshot.

Comment: Just blind guess, it feels like `General::stop` is (wrongly) suppressing `CompiledFunction::cfn`.